# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application and Static Assets Deployment Isolation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, amazon-s3, cdn

I have my application code which handles routing and the restful API, written in golang, however all my client side code is written in Vue and I wanted to isolate the two so I did not have to deploy the entire container when I modified a div. I looked into hosting all my static content on a CDN however its a bit hard to dynamically reference the hash

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href=/static/css/app.c6d9c9fc12c1dbaee77703a4dd731a8b.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=app>
  </div>
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.c40d98f512f01d44a02f.js>

  </script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.94202f7575960a15f341.js>

  </script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.7a2bba27be158abd2c91.js>

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have thought of dynamically pulling from S3 front end, however, this could be costly even if I cache it. Is there any way to tie AWS EB git hooks and pulling onto the appropriate docker containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using cloudfront, pointing my `www.website.com` to the cloudfront site, set up ssl so now my front end deployment is just pushing to s3 essentially.

Then I have my api running on elastic beanstalk and also have ssl set up, so now if I want to hit the api i forward any `api.website.com` to the name of the server. I also setup ssl so everything is encrypted.

I am also versioning my api like so
`api.website.com/v1/<endpoint>`
Deployments are a breeze now!